# Does Primefaces have something with Yasson in Wildfly?

Tags: primefaces, wildfly, resteasy, yasson

I have Wildfly 14.0.1 and due to an error (bug) in Yasson which is the default implementation of JSONB taken by RESTEASY when serializing/deserializing, I have to upgrade the version of Yasson from 1.0.1 to 1.0.4.

When I change the version in Wildfly module, here is the error that I have in the logs:

> SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler] (default task-1) Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1573)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1396)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1091)
>       at com.sun.faces.util.MessageFactory.getMessage(MessageFactory.java:163)
>       at com.sun.faces.util.MessageFactory.getMessage(MessageFactory.java:136)
>       at com.sun.faces.util.MessageUtils.getExceptionMessage(MessageUtils.java:368)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ValidateComponentNesting.addOmittedMessage(ValidateComponentNesting.java:109)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ValidateComponentNesting.access$000(ValidateComponentNesting.java:36)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ValidateComponentNesting$ValidateFormNestingCallback.visit(ValidateComponentNesting.java:91)
>       at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1736)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ValidateComponentNesting.processEvent(ValidateComponentNesting.java:53)
>       at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:147)
>       at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:134)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2292)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2265)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:351)
>       at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:761)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:405)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>       at [APPLICATION_CODE].filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:36)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>       at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
>       at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
>       at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
>       at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
>       at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
>       at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>       at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
>       at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
>       at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I don't understand what is the relation between Yasson and Primefaces since there is nothing in the logs. What I know is that I don't get this error with Yasson 1.0.1.

Comment: The only thing related to PrimeFaces here is the exception handler, not the actual exception.

Comment: @Jasper Can you guess what could be the cause of the error?

Comment: maybe your deployment got corrupt in one way or another... Did you check all the 'norma' obvious causes for this error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my application referenced the 'message' bundle which I didn't have in my deployment archive. What happened is that the older version of Yasson had the same-named bundle which was picked up by my deployment, and the new version of Yasson renamed this bundle, which caused my application to fail.

Comment: So effectively your application was not working correctly before in that it gave wrong lables ;-) maybe use more explicit bundle paths

Comment: Yes, correct. We weren't using this 'message' bundle, it was just declared there when the project started and that's why we couldn't spot this problem :)